# Pending Intent Not Working, Notification Does Not Open Activity

Tags: android, android-notifications

Hello I have the following function that displays notifications in my app, however I suddenly started having an issue where when I click a notification it does not take me to the activity I specified in .setContentIntent(), this is my code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void getNotifications() {
    ArrayList<com.xxxxxx.app234929.models.Notification> notifications = mNotificationsTable.get();

    int requestId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    Intent notificationsIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationsActivity.class);
    notificationsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), requestId,
            notificationsIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inbox = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle(new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_mtgh_notification)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setContentTitle("xxxxxx")
            .setContentText("You have "+(notifications.size() > 1 ? "new updates" :"a new update"))
            .setNumber(notifications.size())
            .setContentIntent(intent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE |
                    Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS))
            .setBigContentTitle("xxxxxx");

    for (int i=0; i < notifications.size(); i++) {
        inbox.addLine(notifications.get(i).getMessage());
    };

    Notification notification = inbox.build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

I've googled a lot of solutions and tried them but none of them worked for me so now I do not know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I changed the name of he activity and it worked, changed it back and it didn't work so I'm gonna say it's just one of those things, will go through my code later on and see what the real issue is/was.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code i use and works perfectly, i have it on a service but you can use in any activity:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, ActivityIWantToOpenOnClick.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyActivity.this, 0, myIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder ncomp = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyActivity.this);
ncomp.setContentTitle("Message Tittle");
ncomp.setContentText("Message Text");
ncomp.setTicker("Message Ticker");                                  
ncomp.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);
ncomp.setAutoCancel(true);
ncomp.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
nManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), ncomp.build());
```